# How to return a response from a fetch in javascript

Tags: javascript, request, fetch

I am having trouble returning the response for a API call in my React Native project.

```
let response = fetch('http://3.133.123.120:8000/auth/token', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        client_id: 'NTMtzF7gzZPU9Ka35UFsDHvpR8e4D1Fy4OPRsurx',
        grant_type: 'password', 
        username: user, 
        password: pass, 
    })
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((response) => this.setState({jsonData: response}))
.then(() => alert('resposne jsonData: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state)));
alert('resposne jsonData: ' + JSON.stringify(response))
```

The code above returns the correct response in the bottom .then() statement, however, I have not been able to use the data outside of the fetch() statement.

Anything I've tried to use outside of the fetch() (like my alert in bottom line) has given me the following...

> {"_40":0,"_65":0,_55":null,"_72":null}

Please also note this is all inside a React class Component

Comment: If you want to use the respond outside fetch function, you should set the response as an async function, or use Promise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` returns a `Promise`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

You already have access to the value in that final then. If you're looking for a way to use the value below without using a callback, you could consider `async/await` style and wrapping this code in a function like so:

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
  const results = await fetch() // put your fetch here
  alert(results.json());
};
```

**fetch info**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

**async/await info**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: I have tried this but when I return the results, it gives me {"_40":0,"_65":0,_55":null,"_72":null} while in the actual function, it gives me the correct output

Comment: does it work if you remove those final 2 `then` statements?: `.then((response) => this.setState({jsonData: response}))` and 
`.then(() => alert('resposne jsonData: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state)));`

Comment: It works as in it returns data.However, I cannot get any of the data out of the function

Comment: @JohnS I've updated the answer so that it is more specific to `fetch`, would would require doing `response.json()` to actually get the json from the response. My original answer applies more to promises in general. You can read more here.